# SQL - GETDATE() not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automationstudio

I have two queries for identifying customers for promotion. The first target is composed of customers who did their last purchase more than 30 days from the current date and the WHERE clause works properly with the following structure:

```
WHERE GETDATE() - Order_Date__c >30
```

When I have to identify customers who did their last purchase exactly 30 days ago,changed the WHERE clause as follows

```
WHERE GETDATE() - Order_Date__c =30
```

but it doesn't work as the result is the same as for >30 days.

What is wrong with the above?

Comment: Have you looked at using a date diff function

Comment: @EazyE yours is the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Use DATEDIFF function:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, Order_Date__c, GETDATE()) = 30
```

You can find more examples in [my SFMC SQL docs](https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/sql/sfmc-sql-date-functions#datediff).

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest going trough those pages and using APEX to help you here :

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm

**First query:**

```
Date dateForSoql = Today().addDays(-30);
WHERE :dateForSoql > Order_Date__c
```

OR

```
WHERE LAST_N_DAYS:30 > Order_Date__c
```

**Second query:**

```
Date dateForSoql = Today().addDays(-30);

WHERE :dateForSoql = Order_Date__c
```

Comment: This is marketing cloud und has nothing to do with apex or soql, therefore your answer does not provide a solution to the question.

Comment: The only place where it is mentioned that this is regarding marketing could is in the tags. Would you please update the title and the questio details.

Comment: Yes the tags are important: They show SQL, Marketing Cloud and Automation Studio. I think the title and details are sufficient in this case. I rarely edit cases, only if highlighting/markup is wrong or tags are missing. The rest should be done by the author.

Comment: Sorry I though you are actually the author.